# How to assign to items to a dictionary from a file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

so i am a beginner programmer and doing the learning to program: crafting quality code course on cousera. i have a file `restaurant_small.txt`

restaurant.txt format is restaurant to rating,

```
georgieporgie:50
dumpling r us:70
queens cafe:60
```

I can read it line by line

```
dictionary = {}
our_file = open(file)
#using an iterator to read files
for line in iter(our_file):
    dictionary = ??
```

i want to be able to build a dictionary `{'restaurant':'rating'}`
How do i go about this, a simple step by step is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dictionary = {}
with open('restaurant_small.txt') as our_file:
    for line in our_file:
       rest, rating = line.split(':')
       dictionary[rest] = int(rating)
```

The [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is the recommended way to work with files that properly handles situations like exceptions and makes sure that the file is always closed at the end. It is roughly equivalent to

```
our_file = open('restaurant_small.txt')
# do the rest
our_file.close()
```

except that if something goes wrong before `close()`, it will be called anyway. A more close equivalent of the `with` statement would be

```
our_file = open('restaurant_small.txt')
try:
    # do the rest
finally:
    our_file.close()
```

Comment: @SuziemacTani Added an explanation and reference

Comment: @LevLevitsky: And if the restaurant happens to have a colon in it's name? Looks like JonClements' answer would still do the right thing.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Lev's answer, but building a lines generator, splitting from the end first, and using a dict comprehension to build it in one go...

```
with open('input') as fin:
    lines = (line.rsplit(':', 1) for line in fin)
    dictionary = {k:int(v) for k, v in lines}
```